# Wordpress shortcode shows as plain text in one view, works in other

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, shortcode

I have this complex loop:

```
<?php

  $args = array( 
      'cat' => 54,
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'posts_per_page' => -1
  );

  $query = new WP_Query($args);   
  $q = array();

  while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 

      $query->the_post(); 

      $a = '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'"><h2>' . get_the_title() .'</h2></a>'
       . get_the_post_thumbnail() . 
      '<p>' . get_the_content("...plačiau") . '</p>';

      $categories = get_the_category();

      foreach ( $categories as $key=>$category ) {

          $b = '<h1 class="thetitle">' . $category->name . '<span>Išskleisti <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span></h1>';    

      }

      $q[$b][] = $a; // Create an array with the category names and post titles
  }

  /* Restore original Post Data */
  wp_reset_postdata();

  foreach ($q as $key=>$values) {
      echo $key;

      echo '<div class="straipsniai">';
          foreach ($values as $value){
            if (count($values) == 1) {
              echo '<div class="vienas">' . $value . '</div>';
            } else if (count($values) == 2) {
              echo '<div class="du">' . $value . '</div>';
            } else if (count($values) == 3) {
              echo '<div class="trys">' . $value . '</div>';
            } else {
              echo '<div>' . $value . '</div>';
            }
          }
      echo '</div>';
  }
```

?>

Which worked for me, gave me this nice list/accordion:
http://bruzienesklinika.lt/web/gydytojai/

Now, each person in the category has some articles as posts and I want a list of their articles under their description. (basic Title + exerpt + read more link)

I've tried to do this by using **"List category posts"** plugin which allows me to use  `[catlist id=24]` shortcode, but the problem is that browser prints it as plain text, source shows `[catlist id=24]`(You can open the most bottom "GYDYTOJA REUMATOLOGĖ" tab to see that). The shortcode does work inside page, which is rendered by single.php, but it does not show when rendered in the loop I gave you in the beginning of the question.

SO, the question is, how do I make the shortcode work in the initial list, where all the categories are listed with posts inside the accordion.

Now it is not the problem of this certain plugin because no shortcodes work in that accordion list.

Or maybe you have an idea how to do this the other way?

Comment: It means the plugin that you are trying use with the shortcode is not running it. You have to do_shortcode(); the output of any plugin or widget so it runs it. That's missing from the plugin you are using.

Comment: I cannot do the do short code, because I need it to work dynamically, there are like 30 posts that need to display 1-10 post inside them, so do short code just isn't a solution here I guess, unless you know how I can do it dynamically :)

Comment: I was just answering your questions why the shortcode was not running. do_shortcode searches content for shortcodes. That's the missing part. If you are still looking to create dynamic shortcodes, it's possible. Check this post for a rough idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546512/dynamic-shortcodes-and-functions-in-wordpress