# WP ACF auto create shortcodes from multiple fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

**GOAL**

I currently have an acf field group with some fields for generic data like phonenumber, email, etc. (all simple text fields).

My goal is to have one function that will loop over all the fields and create a shortcode based on their respective name/label.

**EDIT: PROGRESS**

I think I am getting closer, simplified the whole thing and I believe I am on the right path..

I attached the field group to a post and if I log them like so:

```
$testing = get_field_objects(22);
do_action( 'php_console_log', $testing );
```

I get all the names, values etc. With the help of another snippet I found the shortcodes seem to be at least dynamic since they all stop showing just that there is no value somehow so it all stays blank.

This is the function now:

```
$hlfields = get_field_objects( 22 );
    foreach ( $hlfields as ['name' => $name, 'value' => $value] ) {

        ${"{$name}_fn"} = function() {
            $field = get_field($name, 22);
            return $field;
        };

        add_shortcode($name, ${"{$name}_fn"});

    }
```

---

---

**Original attempt, not working and over complicated:**

I currently have an acf field group with some fields for generic data like phonenumber, email, etc. (all simple text fields).

To be able to insert them all easily using a shortcode, I create one for each field like so:

```
function adresse_shortcode( $adresse ) {
    $adresse = get_field( "adresse", 'option' );
    return $adresse;
}
add_shortcode('adresse', 'adresse_shortcode');
```

While this works fine, I feel like I am repeating myself unnecessarily and also I need to add a function whenever I add a new field.

My goal is to have one function that will loop over all the fields and create a shortcode based on their respective name/label.

I found this snippet to get all fields of a field group by ID:

```
function get_specifications_fields() {

    global $post;

    $specifications_group_id = 13; // Post ID of the specifications field group.
    $specifications_fields = array();

    $fields = acf_get_fields( $specifications_group_id );

    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        $field_value = get_field( $field['name'] );

        if ( $field_value && !empty( $field_value ) ) {
            $specifications_fields[$field['name']] = $field;
            $specifications_fields[$field['name']]['value'] = $field_value;
        }
    }

    return $specifications_fields;

}
```

But I can't figure out how to create the shortcodes now, I have been trying everything I could think of along these lines:

```
function adresse_shortcode( $value ) {
    $specifications_fields = get_specifications_fields();
    foreach ( $specifications_fields as $name => $field ) {
        $value = $field['value'];
        $label = $field['label'];
        $name = $field['name'];
        return $name;
    }
    add_shortcode($value, 'adresse_shortcode');
}
```

I am not well versed in PHP so I am sure it's all sorts of wrong but I have been trying to figure it out for hours and was hoping someone might be able point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hello, @martin I have your code please check and let me know if it works, thanks

Comment: Thanks for looking into it but I think you forgot to add the snippet ;)

Comment: Please have a look: 

function adresse_shortcode( $value ) {
    $specifications_fields = get_specifications_fields();
    $name = '';
    foreach ( $specifications_fields as $name => $field ) {
        $value = $field['value'];
        $label = $field['label'];
        $name = $field['name'];

    }   
    return $name;
}

add_shortcode('adresse', 'adresse_shortcode');

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, also I think the last part to add the shortcode should be something like

add_shortcode( $name, 'adresse_shortcode'); 

so that I can add the various fields by its name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using anonymous functions that should do the trick

```
$hlfields = get_field_objects( 22 );
foreach ( $hlfields as ['name' => $name, 'value' => $value] ) {

    $cb = function() use ($name) {
        $field = get_field($name, 22);
        return $field;
    };  

    add_shortcode( $name, $cb );

}
```

Here's the sources i referred to while answering: [Dynamic function name in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004890/dynamic-function-name-in-php), [Dynamic shortcodes and functions in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546512/dynamic-shortcodes-and-functions-in-wordpress), [PHP: Variable functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)